# Call dynatrace.gradle groovy function from kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy, dynatrace

I have a gradle script dynatrace.gradle, which contains some functions

```
apply plugin: 'com.dynatrace.instrumentation'
dynatrace {
    configurations {
        sampleConfig {
            autoStart {
                applicationId 'getApplicationId()'
                beaconUrl 'getBeaconUrl()'
            }
        }
    }
}

def getApplicationId(){
...
}
```

I want to call this getApplicationId() function from Kotlin class also. Is there any way to achieve this in Android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use dynatrace, use [sentry.io](https://sentry.io/) (: (sorry, just kidding and showing off my bias)

On a serious note - you can't call build logic from within your source code. What you could do, however, is to use BuildConfig for that purpose, so adding something like this to your android config:

```
defaultConfig {
  buildConfigField "String", 'APP_ID', getApplicationId()
}

// and use it like this in Kotlin
BuildConfig.APP_ID
```

Comment: "adding something like this to your android config:" - you mean to add buildConfigField in build.gradle(app) file? If yes, then how to access getApplicationId() function in dynatrace.gradle file from build.gradle?

Comment: OR can I directly create buildConfigField inside dynatrace.gradle and access that in Kotlin?

Comment: I don't think you can, because it's not inheriting from AGP's AndroidExtension

Comment: So Can I somehow access dynatrace.gradle function from build.gradle?

Comment: You mean you want to share your getApplicationId() function? Then I'd create one more gradle file, say, `application_id.gradle` which contains your `getApplicationId()`, and then share this file between `build.gradle` and `dynatrace.gradle` through `apply from: 'path/to/application_id.gradle'`